# Crystal Report database login failure

Tags: asp.net, .net, crystal-reports

Crystal Reports is working on the local machine, local server and other local computer but the moment I add it to our live server it gives me a database login failure.

It has worked before and not working after we made changes to the the reports. We haven't changed any login information and all logins are the same for all the MSSQL's on all the computer.

The server and local is using the same connection string.

Please can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Try to create both 32bit and 64bit connection in client and server as same name!!

Comment: connection is the same name.